# Content larger than screensize with jscrollpane

Tags: jquery, css, jscrollpane

I have a problem regarding jscrollpane. I would like to build a filmstrip-style thumbnail navigation which has roughly this markup:

```
<div class="thumbnails">
<ul class="scroll-pane horizontal-only">
<li><img></li>
<li><img></li>
</ul>
<div>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
.thumbnails {
    background-color:#666;
    height:70px;
    position:fixed;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
    width:100%;
}

.thumbnails .scroll-pane {
    height:70px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}

.thumbnails .horizontal-only { 
    height:auto;
    max-height:70px;
}

.thumbnails li {
    display:block; 
    float:left;
    height:70px;
    width:49px;
}
```

I called jscrollpane on the ul-tag. The desired output is a thumbnail navigation, which is fixed to the bottom of the browser window with horizontal scrolling only. The result I get is a fixed position thumbnail navigation with a vertical scrollbar, because Li elements seem to break at the end of the browser window and start in a new row. Additionally to that I get an horizontal scrollbar that isn't scrollable.

I don't know if I need to change something in my css or in jscrollpane. I'm happy about any comments on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: show your code in a jsfiddle please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ynw2D/3/ There you go.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included jScrollPane's CSS that are required for it to work? They can be found here: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css.

And here is an example of how can you make horizontal and vertical scrolling: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html

**Update**: If you replace CSS rule 'bottom: 0' with 'top:0' for .thumbnails you will see your horizontal bar.

**Update 2**: Have a look at this question: [Scrolling items in DIV horizontally instead of vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427265/scrolling-items-in-div-horizontally-instead-of-vertically/17427364#17427364) It tells how to make vertical scrolling (without jScrollPane though).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I included the scrollpane's css, i just forgot it in the jsfiddle. I know this examples and even there is a horizontal AND a vertical scrollbar in the 'horizontal-only'-example in Chrome 27.

Actually I do see the horizontal scrollbar. But it is not scrollable. And I get a vertical scrollbar, which I do not want.