# Scrolling items in DIV horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: jquery, css, html, stylesheet

Does anyone know of an effective way to float elements so that they scroll horizontally in a container as oppose to vertically?

For example, let's say I have this layout:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">something</div>
  <div class="item">something</div>
  <div class="item">something</div>
  <div class="item">something</div>
  <div class="item">something</div>
</div>
```

I understand that if I give "container" a defined height and width, all "items" can be made to float so that "container" will scroll horizontally.

But what about if I don't know how many "items" there will be? If I don't know the number of items then I don't how wide container should be...

Any thoughts or suggestions? CSS-only suggestions would be ideal but I'm not opposed to using a jQuery plugin if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may just give `white-space: nowrap` to the container and `display: inline-block;` and `white-space: normal` to every `.item` element

Doing so you won't need to previously know the total width of all elements, or calculate it via javascript/jQuery. Then you should just adjust the gap between inline-blocks elements (there're several methods to achieve this: see http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

for the height — given a strict doctype — you may also set `height: 100%;` to `html`, `body`, `#container` and `.item` and `width:100%` to `.item` elements so they will always fit the whole viewport

Comment: +1 I was about to answer the same thing - heres the demo I made http://jsfiddle.net/A7dkV/

Comment: This would only work for a single row correct? Any thoughts on how to allow items to have multiple rows if space permits?

Comment: in that case just use floats with width in `%` and use mediaqueries to check the viewport width

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery to measure the width of inner elements, count them and assing corresponding width to the parent container (like n * m, where n - number of child elements, m - their width).